# Blazor Scheduler Appointment Popup Customization

Tags: blazor, popup, customization, scheduler, appointment

I want to update Telerik Blazor Scheduler Appointment popup customization. I want to add new fields and remove all day event, repeat tabs.

Not required to update all the appointment details. Only possible to view that detail is also fine.

I tried to customize div tag, `AppointmentDetailViewTemplate`, etc. are not support in `TelerikScheduler` tag.

Second thing is I want to add `SchedulerViews` for year. that is also not support in Blazor code.

Does anyone have any solution for Blazor Scheduler appointment popup customization and yearly scheduler view? If so, please let me know...

Thank you

I tried to apply div tag, `AppointmentDetailViewTemplate`, `AppointmentClick`, etc. are not supported in `TelerikScheduler` tag.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write your own component.